# How to change font of country code? I am not abe to change country code font style in my ui. I am using "intl_phone_field 3.1.0" this package

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp7vm.png)
I am not abe to change country code font styl in my ui. I am using "intl_phone_field 3.1.0" this package. Here is my code

```
  Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        child: IntlPhoneField(
                      showCountryFlag: false,
                      showDropdownIcon: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'DMSans',
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: '', border: InputBorder.none),
                      initialCountryCode: 'IN',
                      onChanged: (phone) {
                        print(phone.completeNumber);
                        print(phone.countryCode);
                        print(phone.number);
                      },
                    )),
                  ],
                )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable for country code and assign it to **initialCountryCode**.

```
String countryISOCode = 'IN';
```

For country code text style, you can use.

```
dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(),
```

Complete code.

```
 Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              child: IntlPhoneField(
                            showCountryFlag: false,
                            showDropdownIcon: false,
                            dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontFamily: 'DMSans',
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontFamily: 'DMSans',
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                counterText: '', border: InputBorder.none),
                            initialCountryCode: 'IN',
                            onChanged: (phone) {
                              print(phone.completeNumber);
                              print(phone.countryCode);
                              print(phone.number);
                            },
                          )),
                        ],
                      )),
```

Comment: I have used that, But I want to change font style of country code

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your requirement. Kindly check it.

Comment: Happy to help you. @NeelMoradiya kindly upvote it.

Comment: Sorry bro, i don't have that much reputation.
I am not able to upvote.